# timezonefinder not support by python 3.12

Tags: numpy

Python 3.12 was recently release, but apparently there's a problem with h3's wheel on PyPI.

I'm working on a project that depends on h3, therefore I cannot build my packge unless I drop this dependency

Dependencies:
python3.8+, numpy, h3, cffi

please let me know what's my solotion?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either put in the effort to make your dependencies work with Python 3.12, or you can wait a few months and probably someone else will do that.

Comment: i still haven't found a anything to replace Timezone finder